# case when mysql with multiple conditions

Tags: mysql, case

I made the following case when statement in my sql:

```
SELECT 
*,
CASE
    WHEN lead_time < 14 THEN 0
    WHEN (14 <= lead_time < 21 AND days_passed = 8) THEN 1
    WHEN
        (21 <= lead_time < 28
            AND days_passed = 15)
    THEN
        1
    WHEN
        (28 <= lead_time < 42
            AND days_passed = 22)
    THEN
        1
    WHEN
        (42 <= lead_time < 56
            AND days_passed = 36)
    THEN
        1
    WHEN
        (56 <= lead_time < 84
            AND days_passed = 29)
    THEN
        1
    WHEN
        (56 <= lead_time < 84
            AND days_passed = 50)
    THEN
        1
    WHEN (lead_time > 84 AND days_passed = 36) THEN 1
    WHEN (lead_time > 84 AND days_passed = 57) THEN 1
    ELSE 0
END AS send_email
```

I do not get any error. However, when I check the results I get:

```
# lead_time, days_passed, send_email
99, 15, 1
99, 22, 1
99, 15, 1
99, 8, 1
99, 8, 1
99, 8, 1
99, 8, 1
85, 29, 1
57, 50, 1
18, 36, 1
99, 22, 1
99, 22, 1
99, 22, 1
99, 22, 1
99, 22, 1
15, 15, 1
15, 15, 1
99, 8, 1
99, 8, 1
99, 8, 1
99, 8, 1
```

It seems as if the 'and' in the query behaves as an 'or'. Any idea why?.
Thanks,

Comment: Would you mind telling us what the logic is behind this very complex `CASE`  statement?

Comment: I'm no expert on mysql but I've never seen that shorthand for checking a value is between two numbers. I'd use the Between operator instead. Just out of interest, have you got a reference to docs for the shorthand notation?

Comment: +1 for checking on the logic. Statement seems very brittle, specific to the data that currently exists and not much use in general, which is ok if it's a one-off, but what happens tomorrow when, presumably, days_passed could be 16 instead of 15, etc.

Comment: Is the "21 <= lead_time < 28" correct for mysql? In Postgresql this is incorrert.
You need to use "lead_time >= 21 AND lead_time < 28" or "lead_time BETWEEN 21 AND 27"

Comment: @Ivan, replacing "lead_time >= 21 AND lead_time < 28" made the query work. You can write up an answer to get your points if you want.

Comment: @Chris Flynn the case in which days could be 16 it is obviously covered by the else . I do not understand your criticism here. Please explain.

Comment: @ Tim Biegeleisen, what is so complicated about it?

Comment: I think I understand what you're trying to do. The criticism I raised is probable not valid. It just looks like a very specific query that could break if anything in the data changes. I'd encourage you to think about future-proofing, but if it works and you think it'll continue to work when the rules change, go with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MySQL doesn't support a syntax:

```
min <= expr <= max
```

Such kinds of expressions can be written as:

```
WHERE expr >= min AND expr <= max
```

or with using operator BETWEEN (please note that BETWEEN is inclusive):

```
WHERE expr BETWEEN min AND max
```

Comparison operators in MySQL: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/comparison-operators.html

Answer (score 2):

The comparison `14 <= lead_time < 21 AND days_passed = 8` is checked in sequence, so in a way you have:

```
((14 <= lead_time) < 21) AND (days_passed = 8)
```

Which is always `true` because `14 <= lead_time` equals 1 and thus your comparison is equal to:

```
( 1 < 21 ) AND days_passed = 8
```

You should use a `between` or an `and` for each comparison.